# Get all the minimum points shown in the graph

Tags: python-3.x

I have a CSV file containing latitude, longitude and height information. When I plot the CSV file I get an output like the below graph. I want to get all the possible minimum points as circled with red in the below graph.

`rd = pd.read_csv('right_pt1.csv')
plt.plot(rd['latitude'],rd['heights'],label='low', color='k', marker='.', linestyle='None', alpha=0.3)`

I searched previous stack questions but didn't quite find the same thing I wanted. I could also have missed somethings. Any lead on how to proceed further or links will be helpful.

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjQTp.png)
[image]

Comment: This is simple math - you need to take derivative and find datapoints where local derivative value changes from negative to positive.

Comment: I will read about this and try implementing it. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you define which minimum points you want selected? For example, why is the point directly above 38.66 not selected, but the one just left of 38.68 is?

Comment: Sorry, that I missed to include all the points with the lowest values. I wish to get all the lowest points per latitude.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "per latitude"? Is there a particular fraction of a degree that you're dividing this up by to determine that?

Comment: I was thinking maybe to find the lowest point every 0.01deg interval but by that, I might miss some points. I will remove per latitude from my post.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski,  I read about derivatives (https://towardsdatascience.com/taking-derivatives-in-python-d6229ba72c64). But I am still unclear how to take derivatives for the lower set of points in the graph!? If you could provide me with some pointer links it will be helpful.